# Loss function for logistic regression Tensorflow - formula and tensorflow function results not matching

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am trying to do logistic regression in Tensorflow, with 2 cost functions:

```
dim = train_X.shape[1]
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, dim))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,1))

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(dim,1)))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

y_pred = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(X,W), b)) # using matmul for matrix multiplication. x.shape(768,8) w.shape(8,1)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.add(-tf.multiply(y, tf.log(y_pred)), -tf.multiply(1-y, tf.log(1-y_pred))))
cost2 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y_pred, labels=y))

train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
train2 = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost2)
```

Both these cost functions gives different results although my understanding is that they should give out the same.

```
session = tf.Session()
session.run(init)
print(session.run(cost, feed_dict={X:train_X, y:train_y}))
print(session.run(cost2, feed_dict={X:train_X, y:train_y}))
```

Can someone please explain why that is happening and what changes should I do to get them to show same results?

Comment: how much different your results are? what is the difference between their values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prediction variable for the cost2 variable should be:

```
y_pred2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(X,W2), b2)
```

as the `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` already has the sigmoid function incorporated.